# proc_open() fails with 'Permission denied'

Tags: php, apache, centos

I'm trying to use `proc_open()` to execute a program and print the results. However, I keep getting 'Permission denied'. Have set chmod to 0777 for the script and executable, but to no avail.

`ini_get('safe_mode')` is false.

What could be wrong?

I'm using CentOS, Apache and PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: What are your trying to execute? Do you (the user that executes the PHP script) have permissions to execute that?

Comment: a program made in C. located at /home/emil/workspace/PKE/Debug/PKE. how do I give the user that executes the PHP script permission? I thought that giving the script and the executable 0777 would be enough. sorry I'm a newb :)

Comment: Create a php script, enter `<?php exec("whoami");` and you know who the user is. Put that user in a group that has permissions to execute that file and you are ready to go

Comment: exec("whoami") returned a blank. get_current_user() however, returned 'root' :/

Comment: echo `whoami`; worked, and it returned 'apache'. i added that to my group 'emil', which has read and write permissions to that program, but I'm still getting permission denied.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with an identical setup, and the problem turned out to be SELinux (which is on by default) preventing httpd from executing my external programs. The problem, as I understand it, is that httpd has its own domain and can't touch things outside it. So, the simplest thing to do is to move your scripts into the `/var/www` directory and reset the file contexts:

```bash
restorecon -RF /var/www/
```

If that's not possible, you can instead change the context of your program in-place:

```bash
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/path/to/program(/.*)?"
```

which will basically say that your program belongs to httpd.

Comment: I had the exact same issue but my executable was in `/var/www/` from the beginning, just that I was calling it with an absolute path containing a soft link (e.g. path `/home/user/program` was pointing to `/var/www/program/bin/` path). I replaced the path and worked